# How to install qtiplot on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, 20.04

I am trying to install qtiplot on Ubuntu 20.04. After looking at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/qtiplot it turns out that this package is not yet available in Focal Fossa. I downloaded the 18.04 version (bionic beaver) deb package but I get an error and when I open synaptic package manager it states that this package is broken and it does not give me the option to repair.

Is there a way to install a package from 18.04 onto 20.04?

Very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an account? https://www.qtiplot.com/login_deb.html might have up to date DEB files. Mind that this is payware: 20 usd for 1 user for 1 year so if you need support you need to contact them. We can not help with this.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qtiplot   Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The package if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now

Comment: I was not aware it was payware. qtiplot has always been free on Linux. I guess they might have changed their polices. I guess I should have stayed with 18.04 as they still provide that for free for Linux users. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really you have a way to install the QtiPlot on the 20.04 LTS system.
You have to add special [PPA with Qt4](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4), download [`qtiplot` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/qtiplot) and some its dependencies from 18.04 LTS repository and install it.

Use the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/alglib/libalglib3.11_3.11.0-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libalglib3.11_3.11.0-3_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt-assistant-compat/libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtexengine/libqtexengine1_0.3-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libqtexengine1_0.3-3_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtiplot/qtiplot_0.9.8.9-17_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtiplot/qtiplot-doc_0.9.8.9-17_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./qtiplot_0.9.8.9-17_amd64.deb ./qtiplot-doc_0.9.8.9-17_all.deb
```

and enjoy.

Comment: Thank very much. This work seamlessly and qtiplot works as it should.

Comment: Thank very much. Worked pretty well here to!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add old dependencies, you can run qtiplot in any virtual container.

I have created a [snap wrapper](https://snapcraft.io/qtiplot-wrap) for qtiplot.

Comment: This snap wrapper works great! Thank you so much for providing this!