# Installing QtiPlot or Scidavis on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: software-installation, 20.10

How do I install QtiPlot or Scidavis on Ubuntu 20.10?
I tried to install through the tutorials that are here in the community for version 20.04 and it doesn't work. The terminal says that "it has broken packages and that it depends on libgsl23 (> = 2.5) and that it is not installable".

Answer (score 2):

I have created snap package for qtiplot.

```
sudo snap install qtiplot-wrap
```

That is it. Without extra steps, dependencies and broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

Both applications are outdated. To install QtiPlot we need to add special [Qt4 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4) to the system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo sed -i "s/groovy/focal/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rock-core-ubuntu-qt4-groovy.list
sudo apt-get update
```

For the **QtiPlot** we can adapt my existing method [from similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291921/66509) using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/alglib/libalglib3.11_3.11.0-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./libalglib3.11_3.11.0-3_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt-assistant-compat/libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./libqtassistantclient4_4.6.3-7build1_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtexengine/libqtexengine1_0.3-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./libqtexengine1_0.3-3_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtiplot/qtiplot_0.9.8.9-17_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtiplot/qtiplot-doc_0.9.8.9-17_all.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsl/libgslcblas0_2.4+dfsg-6_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsl/libgsl23_2.4+dfsg-6_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades ./libgslcblas0_2.4+dfsg-6_amd64.deb ./libgsl23_2.4+dfsg-6_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tamuanova/libtamuanova-0.2_0.2-4build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./libtamuanova-0.2_0.2-4build1_amd64.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sip4/python-sip_4.19.7+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y ./python-sip_4.19.7+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -y ./qtiplot_0.9.8.9-17_amd64.deb ./qtiplot-doc_0.9.8.9-17_all.deb
```

Then we need to pin 3 package versions by single long command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-qtiplot
Package: libgslcblas0
Pin: version 2.4+dfsg-6
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libtamuanova-0.2
Pin: version 0.2-4build1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

The main problem here is that `qtiplot` was [not updated](https://repology.org/project/qtiplot/versions) for long time.

For the **SciDAVis** the situation is better, there is fresh [Qt5 port](https://github.com/highperformancecoder/scidavis).
Please note that its installation will remove QtiPlot.
To install SciDAVis from [third-party repository](http://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ahpcoder1&package=scidavis) maintained by the author of SciDAVis, use commands below:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-qtiplot
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/hpcoder1/xUbuntu_20.10/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:hpcoder1.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:hpcoder1/xUbuntu_20.10/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_hpcoder1.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install scidavis
```

---

Note: as you see both methods are hard, so I'll recommend you to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version from scratch and be sure to use one of these applications normally next 4 years. With your current setup one of them (or all two) may be broken on next system upgrade.

Comment: *Both applications are outdated. To install them we need to add special [Qt4 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4) to the system:* AFAIK, this statement only applies to QtiPlot.