# How to include a default color scheme in a snap wrapper virtual container?

Tags: 20.04, kde, qt, colors

This [snap wrapper for qtiplot](https://snapcraft.io/qtiplot-wrap) works correctly with Breeze Light color scheme but it does not work properly with Breeze Dark (kde plasma 5.21.4):

- titles not appearing
- equations are not visible on windows panels
- others

[figure showing qtiplot with Breeze Light and Breeze Dark color scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeoR7.png)

Any way to disable system color scheme only for this program or to include a default color scheme in the virtual container?

[Related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291871/how-to-install-qtiplot-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa/1330404#1330404)